# Push forward of a torsion sheaf under projection map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X= C \times \mathbb{P}^1$ be a rulled surface and $E$ is a vector bundle of rank $n$ on $X$ and $E_t$ be the restriction of $E$ to $\{t\} \times \mathbb{P}^1$. Let $\pi$ be the projection $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$.

Question:
What can we say about  $\pi_*(E_t)$ and $R^1\pi_*(E_t)$ ? Is  $\pi_*(E_t)=\mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}$ and $R^1\pi_*(E_t)=0$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $E_t=i_*(E_{|\{t\}\times \mathbb{P}^1 })$, where $i$ is the embedding of $\{t\}\times \mathbb{P}^1 $ in $C\times \mathbb{P}^1$? If this is the case, $\pi \circ i$ is the identity, so $\pi _*(E_t)=E_t$ and $R^1\pi _*(E_t)=0$.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.